# onTap on map-marker give me NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps

Having problem with onTap on markers in google map.

This is the error

```
05-31 21:46:21.420: E/AndroidRuntime(5541): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 21:46:21.420: E/AndroidRuntime(5541):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.(AlertController.java:753)
05-31 21:46:21.420: E/AndroidRuntime(5541):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.(AlertDialog.java:273)
05-31 21:46:21.420: E/AndroidRuntime(5541):     at my.class.HelloMapView$LocationOverlay.onTap(HelloMapView.java:1361)
```

And this is the code for the error at my.class.HelloMapView$LocationOverlay.onTap(HelloMapView.java:1361)

```
    public class LocationOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>  {
    //public class LocationOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay{
        private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overLayList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private MapView mapView;
        public String pickedlat;
        public String pickedlng;
        private Context mContext;


        public LocationOverlay(MapView mapView, Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
            //super(null);
             super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
             mContext = context;
            this.mapView = mapView; // need it for onTap
            populate();

        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
             return overLayList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
             return overLayList.size();
        }

        public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
             if(!overLayList.contains(overlayItem)){
                  overLayList.add(overlayItem);
                  setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
                  populate();     
             }

           //  populate();
        }

        @Override 
        protected boolean onTap(int pIndex) 
        { 
          OverlayItem item = overLayList.get(pIndex); 
          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); 
          dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle()); 
          dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet()); 
          dialog.show(); 
          return true; 
        }
```

The line refered to in the errorlog is this

**AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);**

And what i can guess from my googling about it, it probably is the mContext not passed along... But i cant get it right...

Please help

Comment: How are you constructing LocationOverlay?

Comment: Not shure what you wanna know now :)

Comment: Post the code when you call the constructor LocationOverlay(mapView, defaultMarker, context)

Comment: LocationOverlay locationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(mapView, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.polis), mContext);

Comment: make sure mContext is not null. If you are calling from an Activity just use this keyword like so LocationOverlay locationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(mapView, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.polis), this);

Comment: Added a answer so you can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

Check your call to the constructor the null value might be passed in there. You can use `this` keyword since `Activity` is a subclass of `Contex`t like so

```
LocationOverlay locationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(mapView, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.polis), this);
```

Or if you are calling from a Fragment use the getActivity() method

```
LocationOverlay locationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(mapView, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.polis), this.getActivity());
```